# UIImage to PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, photosframework

I am trying to convert `UIImage` into `PHAsset` but could not find any solution. All I found is the vice versa (i.e. `PHAsset` to `UIImage`).

The scenario is, I am fetching images from a custom directory into `PHAssetCollection` and showing in `UICollectionView`. I also want to include few more images here from previous screen which are coming from remote source. I don't want to persist remote images into my directory but want to include them in my `UICollectionView`.

Kindly suggest me solution or some good alternate so that the source of `UICollectionView` will be same (i.e. `PHAssetCollection`)

Comment: Found any solution? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You do not want to convert a `PHAsset` to `UIImage`. I do not know if it is possible; it shouldn't be, since `PHAsset` and `UIImage` have different properties, behaviours, etc. The vice versa is possible because all the properties of `UIImage` can be derived from `PHAsset` but not vice-versa.

Instead, change the data source of the collection view to `[UIImage]` while converting `PHAsset` to `UIImage` instead. This approach is clean and solves your other problem of having to convert `UIImage` to `PHImage`.

Comment: I disagree--I have a similar case, where when presenting an array of attachments data, I would present a set of thumbnail icons in a `UICollectionView`.  When getting the attachment data from the camera, it comes back as `UIImage`.  But, the other types of attachments may be files, referenced by `URL`.  This url is then used to determine the how the attachments are presented on the `didSelect(at index)` method.  So the purpose of translation to `PHAsset`, is to obtain a URL in the `assets-library` scheme.

Comment: I really wish people wouldn't authoritatively state their opinion like it's a widely accepted wisdom or rule. It is very possible, and Apple thinks people want to convert a `PHAsset` to a `UIImage` and vice versa. That's why they provided an API for that.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I'll post my answer for people of the future.

What I did in my app was to take a screenshot and save to a dedicated album in the Photos app.

`getAlbum()` in the below example is just a helper method that retrieves the photo album.

`ImageStoreItem` is just a wrapper with two fields: `image: UIImage` and `id: String` for the identifier of the original `PHAsset`.

```
/**
 Saves the image to the album in the Photos app.

 - Throws:
    - `ImageStore.TypeError.accessDenied`
        if the user has denied access to the photo library.
    - An error thrown by `PHPhotoLibrary`.
 */
func saveImage(_ image: UIImage) throws {
    let album = try getAlbum()

    try PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
        let imgReq = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image),
            albReq = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album)!

        albReq.addAssets([imgReq.placeholderForCreatedAsset] as NSFastEnumeration)
    }
}

/**
 Fetches images in the app album.

 - Throws:
    - `ImageStore.TypeError.accessDenied`
        if the user has denied access to the photo library.
    - An error thrown by `PHPhotoLibrary`.
    - `NSError` thrown by `PHImageManager`
        if fetching images from the `PHAsset` list failed.
    - `Globalerror.unknown` if no image was fetched,
        but there is no corresponding error object.
 - Returns:
    An array of `ImageStoreItem`s with the album items.
 */
func getImages() throws -> [ImageStoreItem] {
    let album  = try ImageStore.shared.getAlbum(),
        assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: album, options: nil)
    let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size,
        opt  = PHImageRequestOptions()
    opt.isSynchronous = true

    var res = [ImageStoreItem]()
    var err: Error? = nil

    let handler: (PHAsset) -> (UIImage?, [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void =
    { (asset) in
        { (image, info) in
            if let image = image {
                let item = ImageStoreItem(image: image,
                                      id: asset.localIdentifier)
                res.append(item)
            } else if let info = info {
                if let error = info[PHImageErrorKey] {
                    err = error as! NSError
                } else {
                    var userInfo = [String : Any]()
                    for (key, value) in info {
                        userInfo[String(describing: key)] = value
                    }

                    err = GlobalError.unknown(info: userInfo)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    assets.enumerateObjects { (asset, _, _) in
        PHImageManager.default()
            .requestImage(for: asset,
                          targetSize: size,
                          contentMode: .default,
                          options: opt,
                          resultHandler: handler(asset))
    }

    if let error = err { throw error }

    return res
}
```

The [documentation  on the PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit) isn't too impressive, but take a look here and there and you'll get the hang of it.